# What is the Subject in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

This is an excerpt from a dialogue with a psychologist Elizabeth Brondolo, PhD in APA(Link is here; https://www.apa.org/research/action/speaking-of-psychology/stress-health):

"**And I also really love working with the students, *being* able to generate new hypotheses and *testing* them out in the field.**"

What is the Subject of *"being able to"* and *"testing them out"* in this sentence?

Is the Subject **"I"** or **"students"**? How can you tell?

Comment: The "subject" is an implicit but unstated ***me*** - *I really love [**me**] working with students, [**me**] being able to..., [**me**] testing them...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't the subject an explicit and stated "I"?

Comment: There is no subject, because "being" and "testing" are not acting as verbs in these sentences.  They are gerunds - a verb form in which the verb acts as a noun..

Comment: _"I love things.  The things I love are magic, dancing and tightrope walking."_ Here "dancing" and "tightrope walking" are being used as nouns, just like "magic."

Comment: @Adam: I disagree. To my mind, there *must* be an implied subject associated with the cited usage (even if it *can* be labelled a "gerund" form). If we drop the word completely *(I love working with the students **able to generate new hypotheses**)*, we're obviously forced to interpret the (semantic) "subject" of the remaining highlighted element as ***students***. Once we include it, the subject of that clause really has to be the *speaker* in order for it make sense, but *syntactically*, there's ambiguity (consider *He likes watching girls in his underwear*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is providing a list of things "I also really love". This could be phrased as "And I also really love working with the students; I really love being able to generate new hypotheses; I really love testing the new hypotheses out in the field."